# How to select an element by its value using a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a select box whose options are pre selected by ajax according to a previous value entered by the user.

I need to add text to these options pre selected ONLY.

```
for (i in data) {
        $("#my_select_box_id").val(data[i][0]).attr('selected',true);
        var id_option = data[i][0];

        //this following line doesn't work, why do I do wrong here ?
        $("#my_select_box_id option[value="id_option"]).html(data[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: You have a missing `"` - see the colour coding of the problem line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) if you want currently selected options.

```
$("#my_select_box_id option:selected")
```

Your code didn't work because you were prematurely closing the selector string instead of concatenating. This results in an error.

```
$("#my_select_box_id option[value='" + id_option + "']");
```

Also, the attribute selector should only work on attributes. I don't know about jQuery though because they've historically diminished the distinction between properties an attributes. So it depends if `.attr()` is actually setting the attribute of the property.